# How can I post array of objects in postman in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postman

```
{
  graphName: String,
  lines: [{
    lineName: String,
    xyCoordinates: [
      x: Date,
      y: Number
    ]
  }]
}
```

Comment: I tried raw data as JSON implementation. Also, tried key-value pair implementation. Both in postman.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

Add postman plugin using chrome.

1. Add the URL.
2. Select method as POST.
3. Set Header if necessary.
4. Click on Body. Select **raw** >> **JSON(application/json)** from dropdown.
5. Enter the data in your request body in JSON format. 
   example:

   `{
     "graphName": "String",
     "lines": [{
       "lineName": "String",
       "xyCoordinates": {
         "x": "Date",
         "y": "Number"
       }
     }]
   }`
6. Send the request.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try raw data as JSON with this edited data:

```
{
  "graphName": "String",
  "lines": [{
    "lineName": "String",
    "xyCoordinates": {
      "x": "Date",
      "y": "Number"
    }
  }]
}
```